# Data warehouse modeling - consistency between two fact tables

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I have some trouble to design my data warehouse. Here's the context :

- Financial people register our deals and report a financial snapshot every month. When they register new deals, they also indicates some information like which equipment is sold, at which customer, etc. (our dimensions).
- Project managers add additionnal data to these deals with milestones information (startup project date, customer acceptance date, etc.), also on a monthly basis.

Finance will only use finance information, Project Manager could use both type of information.

Based on this information, I have many possible scenarios, which is the best ?

1st scenario : star schema

In this scenario, I have two separate tables for Finance and Project management. But the thing is that I will have to duplicate reference to dimensions (equipment, customer, etc.) as it is Finance that declare deals and that information have to stay consistant for a same deal.

[First Scenario Schema](http://reho.st/self/33bc40a249c1d97c057d222d5bff9c6bb4d16229.png)

2nd scenario : one common table

As we have the same granularity (both are monthly snapshot), we could merge Finance and Project management information in a single table and proposes two views to the users. But I fear that it will become a mess (different enterprise function in a single table...).

3nd scenario : snowflake schema

We also could add a "Deal" table, containing all references to other dimensions (customer, equipment, etc.).

[Third Scenario Schema](http://reho.st/self/53779913fd5d97597a11117c99c79167b174dcad.png)

Thanks in advice for any usefull advice !

Comment: There is nothing wrong with two facts of different granularities sharing the same dimensions. If you find they share exactly the same dimensions then they probably should be in the same fact. You really need to explain more about the business process to decide how they fit into facts. What are the project managers measuring? dollars? number of milestones? percent progress? Or is it just additional non measure attributes attached to the original deal. Does the project info make any difference to the 'actual' or 'planned' revenue?

Comment: The granulometry is the same (one deal per month) for both PM and financial information. To be more specific about business processes : finance uses financial data for margin consolidation purpose and cost analysis. Project manager will use PM & some financial information to analyze gap between forecasted and actual dates and amounts.